# Create BufferedImage from image format 8BPP

Tags: java, base64, bufferedimage

In my project I receive an Base64-encoded image that is in a greyscale 8BPP format. I am having trouble converting this into a BufferedImage. I have some code that works when I read an image (f.ex png) from disk, base64-encode it and the reverse the process.

Anyway, when I try to convert my received String, everything seems to work, but null is returned. It is not the catch that is invoked, but rather ImageIO.read that returns null.

Any suggestions? I know that the base64 string is valid, because I have tried to save it as a raw file and open it in an editor, which shows the image properly.

This is my code:

```
public static BufferedImage convertBase64StringToBufferedImage(String base64String){
    byte[] pictureBytes = Base64Coder.decode(base64String);

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureBytes);

    BufferedImage image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(pictureBytes));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied InputStream
>       with an   ImageReader chosen automatically from among those currently 
>       registered. The InputStream is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. **If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned.**

Here's the code that gets executed:

```
public static BufferedImage read(ImageInputStream stream)
    throws IOException {
    if (stream == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("stream == null!");
    }

    Iterator iter = getImageReaders(stream);
    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
        return null;                  // <~~~~~ here's your null
    }

    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader)iter.next();
    ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
    reader.setInput(stream, true, true);
    BufferedImage bi;
    try {
        bi = reader.read(0, param);
    } finally {
        reader.dispose();
        stream.close();
    }
    return bi;
}
```

Perhaps you can try explicitly getting an `ImageReader` based on the appropriate mime-type, and do the read code (as seen above) with that reader.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I have now tried that (with all the available mime-types and I get various errors. Most of them saying invalid header or similar.